# Importing data from one table to another through a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application that I am trying to create a check_in page where a list of all checked_in persons will be listed. I am pulling the data, such as name, phone number, address from its original table into the checked_in table. In my view I have a form as follows:

```
        <%= form_for @check_in, :url => {:controller => 'check_ins', :action => 'create' } do |f| %>
          <% @account.children.each do |child| %>
            <%= f.check_box :child_id, :checked => 'checked' %>
            <%= image_tag child.photo.url(:thumb) %>
            <span class="name"><%= child.first %>
            <%= child.last %></span><br/>
          <% end %>
```

The listed child.first and child.last comes from a table that is named children. In my checked_in table my columns are labeled child_first, child_last. How do I transfer the results of this form into that table? I am using a SQL database.

Comment: When you say 'database', do you mean 'table'?

Comment: Yes, tables. Thank you for the correction, I have changed it in my question.